# Server will connect to internet, but will not ping local gateway

Tags: networking, windows-xp, firewall, windows-server-2008-r2

Everything was working fine yesterday, but this morning when I walked in only a computer that was in my firewalls DMZ was able to locate the server. None of the other computers can resolve the FQDN of the server and attempting to ping the IP returns timed out. When I attempt to ping any device on the intranet, the server returnes with "General Error"

Comment: You need to provide more information about your network layout. Did you check the physical layer? NIC, ethernet cables, etc?

Comment: "What Changed?" -- Do not say "Nothing".

Comment: Everything on the physical level is connected and "working". Its a rather small network in which the Server and workstations are connected through an 8-port Netgear firewall. The only thing that has changed is I have been attempting to set up a VPN and went into the firewall to forward the necessary ports to the Server.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a physical or data link layer problem. I've had switches that failed overnight to auto-negotiate a link speed and provided a half on-half off kind of connection (24 port Linksys Gbit switch). Causes very weird problems.

If you can load websites that aren't cached, your server is obviously able to use its routing table, and takes you through **some gateway** (all 0.0.0.0/0 routes will be used for that purpose by your server) to transfer data. Also, this proves that some form of DNS is working. Unless you have a proxy server set up, in which case that server will do all the work for you.

Not being able to ping your gateway from different computer would mean that the gateway could have a problem.

Also, don't forget: if you have a DHCP server or client messing up, you could possibly have an IP address conflict, those can be VERY hard to diagnose. Check for this. I have a Seagate GoFlex Home network attached drive that somehow manages to get the wrong ip-address assigned every single time.

Comment: C.patterson, usually you can't just 'forward' VPN 'ports' since IPsec, L2TP and PPTP don't have any ports. Did you use the appropriate VPN passthrough options of the router?